# How move semantics works here?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I have the following example and I am not sure I fully understand the move semantic logic:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class Player
{
public:
    Player(std::string name)
        : m_name(std::move(name)) {}

private:
    std::string m_name;
};

int main()
{
    std::string s = "Zidane";
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    Player player1(s); // not moved
    std::cout << s << std::endl; // s = "Zidane"

    Player player2(std::move(s)); // moved -> s is empty now
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My explanation is that in the first case (`Player1`), `name` which is an lvalue of type `std::string` is actually copied before the ctor of `m_name` is called, then, the `std::move` acts on the copy, so at the end the copy is empty and its content has been moved to `m_name` using the move ctor. That's why the original argument `s` remains untouched. Is it correct?

In the second case, it's not clear: `std::move` converts the lvalue parameter into a reference rvalue and from there what happen ? In this case, the argument s is empty after the call.

Comment: In the 2nd case, you move `main()::s` into `Player::Player()::name`, thus clearing out `main()::s`. However, note that `move()` need not clear out the source; it just needs to leave it in a valid but unspecified state, so even this is not guaranteed, but it's the sensible thing to do if moving is actually implemented to increase performance.

Comment: Note that `std::move` doesn't actually move anything, it just converts the argument to an rvalue. Later, when constructing the argument `std::string` in `Player`'s constructor, the appropriate `std::string` constructor will be picked

Comment: Adding to @underscore_d's comment, if the implementation does a Small String Optimization, you might find a moved-from string still contains the data when the length is small, or becomes empty when the length is large.

Comment: the variable after `std::move` should not be used in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A new `std::string` is always created to 'populate' the `name` argument, before `Player(std::string name)` is called.

Overload resolution will dictate whether the copy ctor, or move ctor of `std::string` will be called.

### Case 1: `Player player1(s);`

The new string is created by the copy ctor with signature `basic_string( const basic_string& other );`, because 's' was an lvalue.

The total sum of operation that you pay is 1 move & 1 copy constructions of a string:

1. One copy ctor, for the `name` arg to the ctor
2. One move ctor, for the `m_name` class member

### Case 2: `Player player2(std::move(s));`

The new string is created by the move ctor for `std::string`, with signature `basic_string( basic_string&& other ) noexcept;`

In the second case, you call `std::move`, which casts `s` into an rvalue reference. `std::string` has 2 constructors, one which takes a `const std::string&`, the other one takes a `std::string&&`. An rvalue ref can bind to both an lvalue ref and an rvalue ref, but the rvalue ref version is a better match, so it will be selected.

The total sum of operation that you pay is 2 move constructions of a string:

1. One move ctor, for the `name` arg to the ctor
2. One move ctor, for the `m_name` class member

Please do note that, as pointed out by @aschepler and @underscore_d, the move ctor of `std::string` does not need to clear the source string. One should not depend on this behavior, as it is not guaranteed and depends on how the move ctor for the strings are implemented.